# In melee combat, is a poorly optimized high-level Paladin weaker than its optimized mount?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, optimization, paladin

A while ago, I remember reading that past a certain level, a Paladin's combat effectiveness is little more than that of an escort for its superior mount. Given the optimization conditions in the title, is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can absolutely be true.

There are some really powerful feats for a paladin’s special mount. Combine the Devoted Tracker feat with the beastmaster, halfling outrider, Harmonium peacekeeper, and ranger-knight of Furyondy prestige classes (which will consume all your feats to qualify), and you can easily reach nearly 20 HD on your mount while you yourself are less than half that.

Meanwhile, such a paladin has devoted a ton of their own resources to the mount, and has very little combat ability to show for it.

The sad/scary part is, though, that this might be the most powerful way to build a paladin, aside from simple dips for divine grace as part of, e.g., a sorcadin build. Even if the paladin invested all those resources in themselves, there just *aren’t a lot of things you can **do*** with paladin. Divine grace is amazing, and aura of courage is strong, but you can’t really “optimize” either aside from just having a lot of Charisma for divine grace. Those things aside, the paladin just doesn’t really have anything all that good: smite is far too rare to spend resources on, the spellcasting is extremely limited and there’s no “mystic paladin” like there is a mystic ranger, and stuff like mystic fire, Sword of the Arcane Order, and so on just don’t do all that much. The one exception, perhaps, is the mount.

Comment: So, given two high-op Paladins, one optimized for melee combat and the other optimized for mount use, your claim is that the mount Paladin's mount is the strongest in melee? The Paladin himself sucks so much that the conditions in the title of my question were too generous to the mount? Wow.

Comment: @J.Mini I think the claim is that *In melee between Paladin A who is optimized for melee and Paladin B who has optimized his mount for melee, Paladin A loses in a fight against Paladin B's mount.* Eventually at the highest levels this'll come down to initiative as both charge each other, but it'll take a time for Paladin A to catch up to the damage a charging dragoon or flasked avenger was dealing 3–5 levels ago.